# Unable to find a correct output for the two-sum problem

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sum, find, append

Please mention the logical error in the below code as I am not getting a correct output. Also, do share the correct one to get an output of the indices only.

```
def find2Sum(A,X):
    n=len(A)
    for i in range(0,n):
        l=[]
        if X-A[i] in A:
            l.append(i)
    return l
            
nums = [1,4,6,44, 9,8]
target = 14
find2Sum(nums,target)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pradeepta Sahu
When you have `target=8` the answer for `nums=[1,4,6,44, 9,8]` should be none because there are no such numbers. But with your code logic `X-A[i] in A` this for `i = 1` will result into `8-4==4` and it will append index  to L. This is the main logical bug in the code that you have written. Any number that is target/2 will be passed by your condition.

Aside this you also declared your list var inside the for loop but you are returning it outside the for loop.

**This is wrong**

```
for i in range(0,n):
    l=[]
```

**This is right**

```
l=[]    
for i in range(0,n):
```

Comment: Can anyone vote the question so that I can able to question?